# Request Params Node JS 500 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

As the uri is generated is as expected and list data is shown in page but while sending the req in request method, 500 error occurs instead of retruning body.

uri: `http://yufluyuinnepal.com/?vTRIPTYPE=O&vOPSID=O&vSTRFROM=KTM&vSTRFROMTXT=&vSTRTO=PKR&vSTRTOTXT=&vFLIGHTDATE=27-Nov-2018&vRETURNDATE=27-Nov-2018&vADULT=1&vCHILD=0&vNATIONALITY=NP&vNATIONALITYTXT=Nepal&`

```
const uri = `http://yufluyuinnepal.com/?${queryString(query)}`;
console.log(uri);
const req = {
  uri: uri,

};
request(req, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    return reject(error);
  }

  if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    return reject(new Error(`Expected 200 but got ${response.statusCode}`));
  }

  return resolve(body);
});
```

Let me know how can i return body and what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In Request npm module, specify what kind of request is it (GET/POST etc)

```js
// Example GET Request

var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url:
        uri,
      headers:
          {
            // headers as per documentation
          }
    };
    
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if(error){}
  if(response.statusCode !== 200){}
  return resolve(body);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your current implementation with a callback function.

```
const req = {
      uri: uri,
      method: 'GET'/'POST'
    };

    request(req, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        //Do something
      }
      console.log(body);
      //Do something
    });
```

When using `request-promise` module you should write something like this

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
const req = {
   uri: uri,
   method: 'GET'/'POST'
}
rp(req)
    .then((res) => {
        //Do something 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       //Do something with error
    });
```

Comment: wait, are you using the correct `request ` module? I think you are not. The one you are using does not support `promises`, so you can't use `resolve` here. If you want to use one with promises then that's => [this](https://github.com/request/request-promise). Read the documentation clearly and understand the difference

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
let requestp=require('request-promise');

var options = {

    method: 'POST',

    url: 'uri',

    resolveWithFullResponse: true,

    headers: {

                'Accept': 'application/json',

                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'

            },

            body: TextedValue

        };

     

        await  requestp(options).then(async function(Content){

           await requestp(options).then(async function(response){

                if (await response.statusCode == 200)

                    {

                        console.log(Content); // in ur case it is body

                    }

                 else

                    {

                        console.log("Response code "+response.statusCode+" .Try Again Later")

                   }

                })

           })
```

Comment: If you write an answer then  explain what you have changed and why and do not only write `Please try this`, that's nto really helpful because you need to search what has been changed.